# what is the meaning of skew in write skew or read skew

Tags: skew, write-skew

I am learning database transaction in DDIA, There are two concepts of skew in this book, one is unbalanced workload with hot spots, the other is timing anomaly, I can not understand the meanning of 'timng anomaly' and why is called skew.

> The term skew is unfortunately overloaded: we previously used it in
> the sense of an unbalanced workload with hot spots (see “Skewed
> Workloads and Relieving Hot Spots” on page 205), whereas here it means
> timing anomaly.

I want to kow how to explain the menaing of skew in this case

Comment: Check your book, I'm sure it provides additional explanation.

Comment: @Shadow there are some read skew and write skew examples in book, but i can not relate those examples with skew

Comment: Why can't you relate those examples with skew?

Comment: @Shadow I think those examples just describe some phenomenon, but I don not know why these phenomenon is called skew, I can't relate these phenomena tothe meaning of skew(or say I can't understand why is means timing anomaly.)

Comment: This seems to be more of a linguistic problem then, not a programming one.

Comment: @Shadow u are rigjht，I always want to find out Why is it so named，because I think it can helps me remember the concepts better